# Solving the system $XA_k+ YB_k+ XYC_k+ \overline{X}D_k + Y\overline{X}E_k+X\overline{X}F_k+XY\overline{X}G_k+H_k=0$ with $k=1,2$ for complex $X, Y$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Unknowns are two, which are complex numbers $X$ and $Y$ with $|X|<1$ and $|Y|<1$. Remaining values are complex constants.

$$\begin{align}
XA_1+ YB_1+ XYC_1+ \overline{X}D_1 + Y\overline{X}E_1 + X\overline{X}F_1 + XY\overline{X}G_1+ H_1 &= 0 \tag1\\
XA_2+ YB_2+ XYC_2+ \overline{Y}D_2 + X\overline{Y}E_2 + Y\overline{Y}F_2 + XY\overline{Y}G_2+ H_2&= 0 \tag2
\end{align}$$

where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$.

How to solve for the two unknowns when the equations contain the complex conjugate?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I was editing the above using the notation and see you already edited for me. A big thank you for editing for me.

Comment: (You're welcome for the formatting.) One way to proceed is to substitute, say, $X=p+qi$ and $Y=r+si$, and to create two additional equations by conjugating (1) and (2). This gives you a non-linear system of four equations in four unknowns ($p$, $q$, $r$, $s$). The system can be attacked via, say, resultants or Groebner bases, but the process isn't pretty. Can you provide some context about what you're trying to accomplish and/or whether you have reason to expect a "nice" answer? (Add any clarifications to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked.)